# How can we define that an Engine or Airplane is ETOPS compliance?

Tags: terminology

What is the process for obtaining ETOPS certification for an engine or aircraft?

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of ETOPS compliance or "How can we **find out** that something is ETOPS compliant"?

Answer (score 1):

The engine manufacturer must get the certification for this specific model.

The aircraft manufacturer must get the certification for this specific aircraft with this specific engine

The operator company must get itself the certification, particularly the maintenance team.

The operator having been certified must get the certification every aircraft apart.

Certification is 90 min or 120min or 180 min

Answer (score 0):

You don't certify the aircraft or the engine in isolation. ETOPS requires the airframe/engine combination to be certified as a whole. The combination must first meet the basic type certification requirements, then the operator of the aircraft must comply with the registration authority's rules for ETOPS operation in the country of registration.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for the feedback, is there any terms or documentation by that we can said particular asset is ETOPS Certified ?

Comment: From the above explanation you can deduce that you need to check the type certificate and the particular aircraft. I think in some cases you also need to certify the aircraft and engine in combination with the crew, but that I am not sure how it works. I have read that in some countries crews that have already been certified and have ETOPS experience are signed off right away, and others require training (theoretical and practical) but don't quote me on that. :)

Comment: Thanks for such notes, will see and try to use this points in my required stuff :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you like my answer don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. :)